# Can the target of a Sanctuary spell use the Help action in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, helping

I have a Life Cleric who would like to help the party's "Big Guns" be more effective in combat, but do so in a way that *(hopefully)* doesn't increase my healing load.

The [Sanctuary](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) spell forces enemies to succeed on a Wisdom save in order to attack me, unless the spell ends:

> If the warded creature makes an attack, casts a spell that affects an enemy, or deals damage to another creature, this spell ends.

The [Help](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Help) action says I can:

> [...] aid a friendly creature in attacking a creature within 5 feet of [me].  [I] feint, distract the target, or in some other way team up to make [my] ally's attack more effective.

It appears that I could cast *Sanctuary* on myself, wade into the melee so my more effective touch heals are where they're needed most, **AND** use the Help action now and then to give advantage to some of my party's attacks.

Am I correct, or would using the Help action be deemed as an *'attack'* that would end my *Sanctuary*?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Yes; the Help action doesn't end *sanctuary*

The Help action is not an attack or a spell and doesn't deal damage, so none of the ending conditions for the *sanctuary* spell are met. It is consistent with Invisibility, [which Help doesn't end either](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160498), that has similar, although less restrictive limitations.